# How much gas does defining an error consume

Tags: solidity, gas-price

I have written a contract with minimal declaration of errors; Hopping to achieve more readable and concise code. However, if I define more errors, would it cost more gas, if so how much per error?

```
error Contract__GenericError();
error Contract__GenericError2();
error Contract__GenericError3();

.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply defining more errors won't increase your deployment gas costs, for example, these two contracts both cost `77113 gas` to deploy.

```
contract A {
    uint x;
}
```

```
contract B {
    error Zero();
    error One();
    error Two();
    error Three();
    error Four();
    error Five();
    error Six();
    error Seven();
    uint x;
}
```

When you start to implement them into functions, of course, there will be a gas cost but for custom errors, they only take up 4 bytes, so they will usually be cheaper than using traditional `require` statements with hard-coded string error messages.

For reference, compare the new gas costs associated with deploying the contracts after we add a function:

167140 gas

```
contract A {
    uint x;

    function foo(uint _x ) public pure {
        require(_x <= 7, "One");
    }
}
```

130080 gas

```
contract B {
    error Zero();
    error One();
    error Two();
    error Three();
    error Four();
    error Five();
    error Six();
    error Seven();
    uint x;

    function foo(uint _x ) public pure {
        if(_x > 7) {
            revert One();
        }
    }
}
```

And if we add a couple more functions you can see the difference in gas costs increasing further:

273926 gas

```
contract A {
    uint x;

    function foo(uint _x ) public pure {
        require(_x <= 7, "One");
    }

    function bar(uint _x) public pure {
        require(_x <= 14, "Two");
    }

    function baz(uint _x) public pure {
        require(_x <= 21, "Three");
    }
}
```

183797 gas

```
contract B {
    error Zero();
    error One();
    error Two();
    error Three();
    error Four();
    error Five();
    error Six();
    error Seven();
    uint x;

    function foo(uint _x ) public pure {
        if(_x > 7) {
            revert One();
        }
    }

    function bar(uint _x ) public pure {
        if(_x > 14) {
            revert Two();
        }
    }

     function baz(uint _x ) public pure {
        if(_x > 21) {
            revert Three();
        }
    }
}
```

See this quote from the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#revert) about using custom errors:

> Using a custom error instance will usually be much cheaper than a string description, because you can use the name of the error to describe it, which is encoded in only four bytes. A longer description can be supplied via NatSpec which does not incur any costs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, custom errors are a way to save gas

for example:

```
contract A {
     error Contract__GenericError();
     function a() public {
         if(/* some condition */) {
              // do something
         } 
         else {
             revert Contract__GenericError();
         }
     }    
}
```

will cost less gas than:

```
contract B {
    function b() public {
         require(/* some condition */, "Contract__GenericError");
         // do something
    }    
}
```

because in `b()` it costs even more gas to write the error string

Comment: Yeh I Know reverting errors saves more gas. However, how much does it cost to define multiple errors? I wanna know if it's worth it adding more errors than I WOULD LIKE

Comment: hey Ibrahim, i'm not sure I fully understand your case. are u saying u want to define a bunch of errors without using them later?